# Use of parameters dictionary with Python requests GET method

Tags: python, api, rest, python-requests

Trying to retrieve data via the EIA data API (v2):  https://www.eia.gov/opendata/documentation.php.

I'm able to use the API dashboard to return data:

https://www.eia.gov/opendata/browser/electricity/retail-sales?frequency=monthly&data=price;revenue;sales;&start=2013-01

But when I attempt to retrieve within Python using the attached documentation, I don't appear to be returning any values when using the same parameters.

```
url = 'https://api.eia.gov/v2/electricity/retail-sales/data/?api_key=' + API_KEY

params = {
    "frequency": "monthly",
    "data": [
        "revenue",
        "sales",
        "price"
    ],
    "start": "2013-01"
}

if x.status_code == 200:
    print('Success')
else:
    print('Failed')  
    
res = x.json()['response']
data = res['data']
```

If I print the url created by the GET method, and compare to API url included in the dashboard, the issue appears to be in the way the GET method is attempting to retrieve items from the `data` parameter:

**Works**

[https://api.eia.gov/v2/electricity/retail-sales/data/?frequency=monthly&data[0]=price&data[1]=revenue&data[2]=sales&start=2013-01&sort[0][column]=period&sort[0][direction]=desc&offset=0&length=5000](https://api.eia.gov/v2/electricity/retail-sales/data/?frequency=monthly&data%5B0%5D=price&data%5B1%5D=revenue&data%5B2%5D=sales&start=2013-01&sort%5B0%5D%5Bcolumn%5D=period&sort%5B0%5D%5Bdirection%5D=desc&offset=0&length=5000)

**Doesn't work (returned by GET method):**

https://api.eia.gov/v2/electricity/retail-sales/data/?api_key=MY_API&frequency=monthly&data=revenue&data=sales&data=price&start=2013-01

**Can anyone provided guidance on how to coerce the GET method to pass my data parameters in the same way as the API dashboard appears to?**

Comment: Seems to me you could use `"data": "price;revenue;sales;"` in the params dict.

Answer (score 1):

Your **data** in **params** not formatted correctly in url. Try this if you want the url to be formed as in your working version:

```
url = 'https://api.eia.gov/v2/electricity/retail-sales/data/?api_key=' + API_KEY

data = [
        "revenue",
        "sales",
        "price"
    ]

params = {
    "frequency": "monthly",
    "start": "2013-01"
}
for index in range(0, len(data)):
    params[f"data[{index}]"] = data[index]

response = requests.get(url, params = params)
```

But if the server is adequate, then square brackets in the name of the **data[]** parameter are enough:

```
url = 'https://api.eia.gov/v2/electricity/retail-sales/data/?api_key=' + API_KEY

params = {
    "frequency": "monthly",
    "data[]": [
        "revenue",
        "sales",
        "price"
    ],
    "start": "2013-01"
}
```

Comment: Kudos, the latter is what I'm looking for...but I've never seen this syntax before (and data =[] creates a list natively).  Can you provide any context or documentation for this?

Comment: @Chris , what a cocrete syntax you interest?

Comment: Have just never seen this sort of syntax when passing lists.  How/when/why is it necessary

Comment: @Chris , needed every time you send many parameters with the same name to the server. [See this](https://medium.com/raml-api/arrays-in-query-params-33189628fa68) Chapter - **Array in query params**