# Issues sending params dictionary to RESTful API

Tags: python, python-requests

Getting an error when trying to pass query params within a requests get call.  Using the following in python:

```
import requests as re
url = 'https://api.eia.gov/v2/natural-gas/pri/fut/data/?api_key=' + API_KEY

params = {
    "frequency": "daily",
    "data": [
        "value"
    ],
    "start": "2021-01-01",
    "facets": {
        "series": [
            "RNGWHHD"
        ]
    },
    "offset": 0,
    "length": 5000
}

x = re.get(url = url, params = params)

if x.status_code == 200:
    print('Success')
else:
    print(x.text) 

{"error":"Invalid format for facet 'series'. Must provide which facet and an array of values. For example, to filter by location for VA and CA: facets[location][]=VA&facets[location][]=CA","code":400}
```

I'm able to return data using the [dashboard as reference](https://www.eia.gov/opendata/browser/natural-gas/pri/fut?frequency=daily&data=value;&facets=duoarea;&duoarea=RGC;&start=2014-01-01&sortColumn=period;&sortDirection=desc;).  And also by including params in the requested url as follows:

```
'https://api.eia.gov/v2/natural-gas/pri/fut/data/?frequency=daily&data[0]=value&facets[series][]=RNGWHHD&start=2021-01-01&sort[0][column]=period&sort[0][direction]=desc&offset=0&length=5000&api_key=' + API_KEY

x = re.get(url = url)
```

But not by passing a parameter dict to `get`.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Seems that requests is not building the url as you expect

if you see the url after you call requests.get function, you should see something like this:

```py
>>> x.url
'https://api.eia.gov/v2/natural-gas/pri/fut/data/?api_key=API_KEY&frequency=daily&data=value&start=2021-01-01&facets=series&offset=0&length=5000'
```

So consider somehow parsing your params

See [Use of parameters dictionary with Python requests GET method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75417334/use-of-parameters-dictionary-with-python-requests-get-method) question